# iOS - Error while uploading images from gallery

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, avasset

I'm building extension for my iOS app to upload Photos/Videos from gallery.
But When trying to convert url to NSData I got this error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “IMG_0015.JPG” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/6689587C-2A44-45D1-9DFF-841A3B890051/IMG_0015.JPG, NSUnderlyingError=0x12298d360 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Sometimes I got this error too

```
Code=257 "The file  couldn't be opened because you don’t have permission to view it
```

All permissions are set, so what's wrong here?

Comment: You may not have permission to the file. Your extension has limited and different permission with host application.

Comment: You can't convert Url to NSData, instead you need to get PHAsset and then you can convert that image to Data.